# smart way to "break" for loops when iterating

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I want to iterate over a list of items and put them in a table, but I want the table to break after x items. I am using bootstrap5 to format my table.

I want to display the following dict as table:

```
{'store_6': [ProductData(id=1516004, stat=0), ProductData(id=1516028, stat=2)]}
{'store_3': [ProductData(id=590418, stat=5), ProductData(id=590422, stat=1), ProductData(id=590423, stat=1), ProductData(id=590424, stat=2), ProductData(id=590425, stat=0), ProductData(id=590427, stat=4), ProductData(id=590432, stat=0)), ProductData(id=1590418, stat=0), ProductData(id=1590422, stat=0), ProductData(id=1590423, stat=0), ProductData(id=1590424, stat=0), ProductData(id=1590425, stat=0), ProductData(id=1590427, stat=2), ProductData(id=1590432, stat=0)), ProductData(id=1690418, stat=0), ProductData(id=1690422, stat=0), ProductData(id=1690423, stat=1), ProductData(id=1690424, stat=3), ProductData(id=1560425, stat=0), ProductData(id=1690427, stat=5), ProductData(id=1690432, stat=0))]}
```

I want to have a table like this:
[image]

where every row starts with the store name and then uses one column for every product. If a store has more than 10 products, the first column is blank. There cannot be more than 32 products.

I have a working solution, but it looks ... quirksy:

```
{% for store_number, products in all_store_data.items  %}
    {% for product in products %}
        {% if forloop.first %}
            <tr>
                <td class="col-sm-2">{{ store_number }}</td>
        {% endif %}

        {% if forloop.counter == 11 or forloop.counter == 21 or forloop.counter == 31 %}
            <tr>
                <td class="col-sm-2"></td>
        {% endif %}
        
        <td class="col-sm-1">   
            {{ product.id }}
        </td>

        {% if forloop.last %}
            {% for add_row in forloop.counter|fill_until_10 %}
                <td class="col-sm-1"></td>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

        {% if forloop.counter|modulo:10 %}
            </tr>
        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

with two little helper filters:

```
@register.filter
def modulo(num, val):
    return num % val == 0

@register.filter
def fill_until_10(counter):
    return range(10 - counter % 10)
```

my problem now is, that I do not really think the code in the template is "easy to read" - anyone got a better idea on how to approach this?
I wanted to avoid `mark_safe` magic and therefore tried to avoid additional template filters.

Comment: Are you open to using something other than a table? It doesn't seem like the best fit for your data

Comment: no ... I really wish to stick to a table, as it helps me avoiding a lot of `<div>` magic :)

Comment: FYI, there is already a built-in version of your `modulo` filter https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby

Answer (score 1):

I would process the data in Django view so every store contains a list of lists (one list for every row). Then rendering would be way easier for Django Template processor logic.

eg.

```py
data = {
    "store_6": [[ProductData(id=1516004, stat=0), ProductData(id=1516028, stat=2)]],
    "store_3": [
        [
            ProductData(id=590418, stat=5),
            ProductData(id=590422, stat=1),
            ProductData(id=590423, stat=1),
            ProductData(id=590424, stat=2),
            ProductData(id=590425, stat=0),
            ProductData(id=590427, stat=4),
            ProductData(id=590432, stat=0),
            ProductData(id=1590418, stat=0),
            ProductData(id=1590422, stat=0),
            ProductData(id=1590423, stat=0),
        ],
        [
            ProductData(id=1590424, stat=0),
            ProductData(id=1590425, stat=0),
            ProductData(id=1590427, stat=2),
            ProductData(id=1590432, stat=0),
            ProductData(id=1690418, stat=0),
            ProductData(id=1690422, stat=0),
            ProductData(id=1690423, stat=1),
            ProductData(id=1690424, stat=3),
            ProductData(id=1560425, stat=0),
            ProductData(id=1690427, stat=5),
        ],
        [ProductData(id=1690432, stat=0)],
    ],
}
```